# My script doesn't scrape all of Yelps restaurants

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

My script stops scraping after 449th Yelp restaurant.

## Entire Code: https://pastebin.com/5U3irKZp

```
for idx, item in enumerate(yelp_containers, 1):
    print("--- Restaurant number #", idx)
    restaurant_title = item.h3.get_text(strip=True)
    restaurant_title = re.sub(r'^[\d.\s]+', '', restaurant_title)
    restaurant_address = item.select_one('[class*="secondaryAttributes"]').get_text(separator='|', strip=True).split('|')[1]
```

The error I am getting is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kenny/MEGA/Python/yelp scraper.py", line 41, in 
    restaurant_address = item.select_one('[class*="secondaryAttributes"]').get_text(separator='|', strip=True).split('|')[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that some restaurants are missing the address, for example this one:

[image]

What you should do is check first, if the address has enough elements before indexing it. Change this line of code:

```
restaurant_address = item.select_one('[class*="secondaryAttributes"]').get_text(separator='|', strip=True).split('|')[1]
```

to these:

```
restaurant_address = item.select_one('[class*="secondaryAttributes"]').get_text(separator='|', strip=True).split('|')
restaurant_address = restaurant_address[1] if len(restaurant_address) > 1 else restaurant_address[0]
```

I ran your parser for all pages and it worked.

Comment: Thank you so much Andrej. 

Just curious, do you happen to know why the script always stops at 959th restaurant? I have my for loop set up so that it should scrape to page 960.

for i in range(0, 960, 30):

Comment: @Kay `range(0, n)` is going to iterate from `0` to `(n-1) ` inclusive. Here is the official explanation https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#range